# Can't Attach Northwind database as it's version 661. Server supports 612 and earlier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to attach the Northwind database to my SQL Server Express environment. I'm getting the following error message though:

> The database 'northwind' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Do I need to download some update to SQL Server? I have the full version of SQL Server 2012 Management Studio version 11.0.2100.60 according to the "About" section.

Edit: I did find similar questions but the numbers did not match the ones I got. That linked example is not the same. It's 661/662, mine is 661/612

Comment: Yeah - you have **Management Studio** 2012 - but what **engine** version are you running against? See the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` - what does it tell you? You need to have the Northwind database **for that version** of SQL Server - the databases are not downward compatible...

Comment: This question is answered repeatedly in the first 6 or 7 posts in the **Related** list to the right of your question,which means you didn't even bother to search before posting. Shame on you.

Comment: I did search but the numbers were different in the other scenarios. That linked example is not the same. It's 661/662, mine is 661/612

Comment: The numbers being different doesn't matter. The solution is the same. The second one in the list uses 655 and 612, which still means the DB version is greater than the server version,  and the solution to the problem is the same. The third and fourth use 661/655 as well.

Comment: Database version 662 is SQL Server **2008 R2** , while your engine you're connecting to obviously only support version 612 (SQL Server 2005). You ***CANNOT*** under any circumstances restore a **newer** database to an older engine - just doesn't work - don't waste your time trying.... you need to use the same (or a newer) engine. So either restore your database to the **2012** instance (if you have one), or download a SQL Server **2005** version of Northwind